# How to parse in C

Tags: c, parsing, split

My idea is to save in multiple variables the data from a file. This file has the followin structure:

```
Cat;Small;Animal
Dog;Big;Animal
Tea;Warm;Drink
```

For that I need to split the text in the ';' and in the '\n'.

Then I want to save in an array this data like in this example:

```
char object[3] = {"Cat", "Dog", "Tea"};
char description[3] = {"Small", "Big", "Warm"};
char type[3] = {"Animal", "Animal", "Drink"};
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use `fgets` to read a line, and `strtok` to split the line.

Comment: The three arrays need to be `char *object[3] = { … };` etc.

Comment: Why not save them in `struct`s?

Comment: You can either manually parse with a pair of pointers, or use `strtok` with a delimiter of `";\n"`. There are many examples of how to do both on this site. Search `"C strtok split string"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a function to read lines from a file, such as `get_line` (POSIX), or [this portable `read_line` function](https://gist.github.com/Druid-of-Luhn/d1a85f366ceecfc3c2dc5491e3d25cb4) that I just wrote for this, you can then split the line into tokens using `strtok` with the delimiter set to `";"` (make sure to remove the trailing `\n` from the line first). You can then copy each token into the relevant array.

However, as your file format is essentially a CSV file, and you might end up wanting to add more columns or rows in the future, you could use something like [`libcsv`](https://github.com/rgamble/libcsv) ([documentation](https://github.com/rgamble/libcsv/blob/master/csv.pdf)).

A quick solution to this might look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

extern size_t read_line(FILE *file, char **line);

typedef enum Category {
    OBJECT, DESCRIPTION, TYPE
} Category;

Category next_category(const Category category)
{
    return (Category) ((category + 1) % 3);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *object[3];
    char *description[3];
    char *type[3];
    size_t counter = 0;

    FILE *file = fopen("example.csv", "r");
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t length = 0;
    while ((length = read_line(file, &line)) > 0 && counter < sizeof(object)) {
        Category token_category = 0;
        char *next_token = strtok(line, ";");
        while (next_token != NULL) {
            size_t token_length = strlen(next_token);
            switch (token_category) {
                case OBJECT:
                    object[counter] = calloc(token_length, sizeof(char));
                    memcpy(object[counter], next_token, token_length);
                    break;
                case DESCRIPTION:
                    description[counter] = calloc(token_length, sizeof(char));
                    memcpy(description[counter], next_token, token_length);
                    break;
                case TYPE:
                    type[counter] = calloc(token_length, sizeof(char));
                    memcpy(type[counter], next_token, token_length);
                    break;
            }
            // Read the next token from the same string
            next_token = strtok(NULL, ";");
            token_category = next_category(token_category);
        }
        free(next_token);
        free(line);
        ++counter;
    }
    fclose(file);
    printf("Objects:      %s, %s, %s\n", object[0], object[1], object[2]);
    printf("Descriptions: %s, %s, %s\n", description[0], description[1], description[2]);
    printf("Types:        %s, %s, %s\n", type[0], type[1], type[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nit - saving `size_t len = strlen(next_token);` allows `memcpy (object[counter], next_token, len + 1);` avoiding scanning for the end-of-string a second time with `strcpy` (you already scanned for the end-of-string with `strlen`). `sizeof(char)` is always `1`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Well noticed. I haven't written C in a while, and `strcpy` and `memmove` (for overlapping memory). I just used `strlen` for simplicity, but with `length` already saved, I agree that `memcpy` is better. As to `sizeof(char)`, I use it because it matches all other uses of the `malloc` family, for `void *`, `int`, etc…

Answer (score 1):

U should not declare char array if u want to store like this.

```
 char object[3] = {"Cat", "Dog", "Tea"};
 char description[3] = {"Small", "Big", "Warm"};
 char type[3] = {"Animal", "Animal", "Drink"};
```

U should declare array of char pointer

```
char *object[] = {"Cat", "Dog", "Tea"};
char *description[] = {"Small", "Big", "Warm"};
char *type[] = {"Animal", "Animal", "Drink"};
```

Comment: You do not need `[3]`. Use `[]` instead and let the compiler work out the size of the array

Comment: @ Ed Heal I agree.If we are doing direct initialization.